# Value of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{11}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{11}+\sqrt{15}}+\cdots$ ($n$ terms)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Sum $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{11}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{11}+\sqrt{15}}+\cdots \text{ ($n$ terms)}$$

I know how to use the telescoping series method when the terms are in product. Here i tried to make $f(n+1)-f(n)$ form but failed to do so. How do we go about with this one?

Any help is welcome,
Thanks.

Comment: Is this series convergent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Multiplying top and bottom by the denominator with a $-$ sign, we can rewrite this as

$$\frac{\sqrt 7 - \sqrt 3}{7 - 3} + \frac{\sqrt{11} - \sqrt 7}{11 - 7} + \frac{\sqrt{15} - \sqrt{11}}{15 - 11} + \dots + \text{ final term}$$

This does telescope.

Comment: @t.bongers . I can see that it telescopes, all denominators are 4, but I fail to see that the infinite term goes to zero. I am having a brainblog or I just don't see it. Is the given series divergent?

Comment: There is no infinite series. The problem asks for the sum after $n$ terms.

Comment: @martycohen In that realm, ok makes sense. I was thinking as an infinite series since that's whatI have been doing with my students lately. They are spinning infinitely in my head at the moment...

Answer (score 6):

Note that the $n^{th}$ term is
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{4n-1} + \sqrt{4n+3}}$$
Rationalize the denominator to get
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{4n-1} + \sqrt{4n+3}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{4n+3} - \sqrt{4n-1}}4$$
Now use telescopic cancelation to obtain what you want.